# Saving Matlab object instance results in an infinite loop

Tags: matlab, file, save, instance, handle

*Set up* :

I have [created](https://github.com/ATajadod94/ALITrack) a Matlab **handle** class called "Participant' for reading and operating on certain research data. I have created multiple instances of this object and saved them to the hard disk with no problem. I have also checked my problematic instance to ensure that it is functional in Matlab. There does not seem to be any bugs with the instance.

*The problem*

However, on certain instances, for no clear reason to me, Matlab gets stuck on an infinite loop writing to disk. This is evident in looking at the .mat fiels output's modification date which keeps changing per minute and in the fact that my Matlab instance slows down tremendously.

The code to create the the participant is

```
myparticipant = participant([basedir ,p_folder{p_num}]);
```

*Methods tried*

I have saved to disk by right clicking in the workspace which results in the problem above.

Using the save function, I get :

```
 save('test.mat', 'myparticipant')

Error using save
Error closing file test.mat.
The file may be corrupt.
```

and of course it won't load after.

Any insight would be appreciated as I'm not sure how to start approaching this issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's infinite and not just a lot of data being saved? What is the magnitude of data you're working with? How does the current problematic dataset differ from the multiple instances that were created in the past without issue?

Comment: Hi, it was infinite indeed but your comment about the size of the data was extremely helpful. I was able to solve the issue!

Essentially, the problem was that because I was using a handle class, the size of my data shown in working memory was much smaller than the real size of data. Because my data was bigger than 2gb, I had to use Matlab's "-V7.3" keyword to save to file! 

The error Matlab produced was non informative , I assume because of the handle class. 

Thanks again :)

Comment: How did it throw an error if it was in an infinite loop?

Comment: Please do not edit questions or titles to add unnecessary information. The solution does not belong in the title.

Comment: @excaza As I mentioned in the question description "This is evident in looking at the .mat fiels output's modification date which keeps changing per minute and in the fact that my Matlab instance slows down tremendously."

Comment: None of that means it's an **infinite** loop, it just means a lot of data is being saved.

Comment: Nope, it went on for a much longer amount of time that it takes to save 2GB data.. It went on literally for 24 hours. When I solved it using the method below, it took seconds.

Comment: You could have just said "it took 24 hours" 2 days ago, not sure why it was such a difficult question to answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to excaza's comment I was able to spot this issue. As I explained in my comment response, the problem was that *because I was using a handle class*, the size of my data shown in working memory was much small. However, my data size was actualy bigger than 2gb. In these cases, you have to use Matlab's "-V7.3" keyword to save to file! adding that flag did it for me.